# Is there a way to create a interface that shows archieves from a FTP Server in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I have a FTP Server, and I want to shows all the archieves that exist on this server using some source of graphics, like swing for example.

I've tried getting the names of the files but it doesn't really show the archieves itself, and didn't find any solution besides that.

Also the function it's not really working on this project, I don't really know why it doesn't respond, but using in other projects it's working as expected.

```
package view;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

import java.io.*;

import br.com.consiste.FtpConnector.*;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.Button;

public class ViewTela {

private JFrame frmServidorFtp;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ViewTela window = new ViewTela();
                window.frmServidorFtp.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */
public ViewTela() throws IOException {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void initialize() throws IOException {

    frmServidorFtp = new JFrame();
    frmServidorFtp.setTitle("Servidor FTP");
    frmServidorFtp.setBounds(100, 100, 375, 445);
    frmServidorFtp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmServidorFtp.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    List list = new List();
    list.setBounds(10, 43, 339, 147);
    frmServidorFtp.getContentPane().add(list);

    Button button = new Button("New button");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    button.setBounds(35, 224, 84, 33);
    frmServidorFtp.getContentPane().add(button);

    FTPConnection connect = new FTPConnection();
    FTPClient ftpClient = connect.createConnection();
    FTPUtil util = new FTPUtil();

    ArrayList<String> pastes = util.listPastes(ftpClient);
    int size = util.listPastes(ftpClient).size();
    System.out.println(size);

    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
        pastes.get(index);
    }
}
}
```

My POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.com.consiste</groupId>
    <artifactId>FtpInterface</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FtpInterface</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.consiste</groupId>
            <artifactId>FtpConnector</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Are you able to dump the FTP servers filelist as Strings ? If not: start there and minimize your problem by leaving out swing

Comment: yes I am able to get all the files from the server as an ArrayList of strings

Comment: [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html); [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). You're probably also going to want to look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: 1) Please note you're mixing AWT components (`List`, `Button`) with Swing components (`JFrame`). You should use all Swing components (i.e: `JList`, `JButton`). 2) *"yes I am able to get all the files from the server as an ArrayList of strings"* Ok but you don't seem to add those strings to any Swing component model (i.e: `ListModel` attached to a `JList` component) so it makes sense you won't see them.

Comment: " I am able to get all the files from the server as an ArrayList of strings"  so your question is actually how to display ArrayList of Strings using swing ? If so, post an apropriate [mcve]: hard-code such ArrayList as test data, and remove all unrelated information.